# Установить grub без замены загрузчика

Tags: linux, windows, grub, dual-boot

После установки Windows первичным загрузчиком стал его собственный.
Имеется Linux Mint, поэтому нужно иметь grub.

Однако, вместо стандартного варианта, при котором первичным загрузчиком становится grub, я хочу установить grub на отдельный раздел и прописать в виндовом загрузчике команду для передачи управления grub'у. Естественно, виндовый загрузчик должен остаться первичным.

Как установить grub, чтобы получилась такая конфигурация?

Comment: http://superuser.com/q/187586/454489

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, вчера попадалось несколько страниц, где писалось про предупреждение при подобном вызове, а в качестве ответа говорилось, что `sda1` это не диск и надо `sda`. Я правильно понимаю, что мне надо будет указать ключ `--force` чтобы он установился именно на раздел?

Comment: не знаю. проверьте. в документации написано: [The argument can be either a device file (like '/dev/hda') or a partition specified in GRUB's notation](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/legacy/Installing-GRUB-using-grub_002dinstall.html). // опцию `--force` (и аналогичные) в любой программе, пожалуй, стоит применять в том случае, если хорошо представляешь, что собираешься делать.

Comment: но я бы на вашем месте, ни на секунду не заморачиваясь с весьма сноровистым проприетарным п.о., поставил бы *grub* (точнее, его «stage 1») в *mbr*. ему, по-моему, гораздо проще объснить, что существуют и другие операционные системы, которые тоже хотелось бы загружать. но если вы знаете, как управиться с загрузчиком от *ms*, то с *grub-овским* «stage 1» вам ничего делать и не надо: это уже дело загрузчика *ms* — загрузить «stage 1» (или «stage 1.5» из `/boot/grub`). про *stage* даже в википедии популярно написано: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, я надеюсь, что [EasyBCD](//neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) с виндовым загрузчиком разберётся.

Comment: хозяин-барин, как говорится. но раз не умеете настраивать и *ms*-загрузчик, самое логичное, с моей точки зрения, воспользоваться уже имеющимся по рукой инструментарием. тем более, что он (инструментарий) отлично умеет загружать и *ms/windows* в том числе. впрочем, всему своё время: насколько помню, вы совсем недавно «познакомились» со свободным п.о., так что всё у вас впереди.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, нет, как загрузить я не спрашивал - меня именно установка интересует. Так что, правку заголовка я откатываю.

Comment: я сделал дополнение к ответу.

Answer (score 4):

**предуведомление**: далее изложенное весьма упрощено и относится только к «традиционной» (или «старой») схеме разбивки диска под названием [*dos partition table* (*mbr-based partitioning*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record). хотя, вероятно, отчасти справедливо и для [*guid partition table* (*gpt*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table). но точно не относится к [*unified extensible firmware interface* (*uefi*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_system_partition).

---

упрощённо говоря, *bios* загружает в память первые 512 байт с указанного в его настройках блочного устройства, и передаёт управление этому «кусочку кода» (в терминах *grub-а* это называется «загрузчик первой стадии» — *stage 1 loader*).

помимо исполняемого кода там есть и ещё кое-какая необходимая этому самому коду информация. понятно, что в такой мизерный объём кода что-то разумное уместить довольно сложно, и, фактически, этот код всего лишь загружает другую, значительно бо́льшую порцию кода (*stage 2*), и передаёт управление ей.

откуда именно брать эту вторую порцию, «загрузчик первой стадии» узнаёт из той самой информации, которая записана рядом с ним в те самые 512 байт. в числе прочего там записаны, как минимум: адрес блочного устройства (ведь *stage 2* может располагаться и на другом б.у.) и адрес сектора(-ов), который(-е) надо загружать в память.

почему адрес сектора, а не имя файла? потому что в 512 байт невозможно «уложить» код, который умел бы работать с *файловой системой*.

кстати, к слову: в случае перезаписи файла со *stage2* его физическое местоположение с большой вероятностью изменится, и, соответственно, потребуется и корректировка содержимого тех самых 512 байт «загрузчика первой стадии».

а вот уже тот код, что загрузился из *stage 2*, «понимает» и файловые системы, и конфигурационные файлы может прочитать, и вывести диалог пользователю, основанный на этих конфигурационных файлах, и выбранную программу, выполняющую функции ядра, загрузить (ту, загружать которую «обучен»: [*ntoskrnl.exe*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ntoskrnl.exe), *linux* и т.д. и т.п.).

*stage2*-загрузчик от компании *ms*, понятно, не «обучен» загружать программу *linux*, а *stage2*-загрузчик *grub* (равно как и [*lilo*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LILO_%28boot_loader%29) и прочие) не «обучен» загружать *ntoskrnl.exe*.

но все они могут загрузить **другие** *stage1*-загрузчики (и даже *stage2*-загрузчики) и передать управление **им**.

---

а далее можно говорить лишь о степени автоматизации настройки этого процесса.

1. в случае загрузчика от компании *ms*, понятно, никакой автоматизации настройки не предусмотрено: облегчение процесса использования «чужой» операционной системы — это «удар ниже пояса», т.е., по кошельку. как говорится, «это просто бизнес, ничего личного».

   для настройки нужно разжиться «загрузчиком первой стадии», записать эти 512 байт в файл (например, `c:\bootsect.aln`) и [добавить строку в секцию *operating systems*](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/LG/issue36/larriera.html) конфигурационнога файла загрузчика `c:\boot.ini` примерно такого содержания:

   ```
    c:\bootsect.aln="alien operating system"
   ```

   не забудьте ещё каждый раз вручную обновлять содержимое этого 512-байтного файла после обновления *stage2*-загрузчика, на адреса секторов с которым он (файл) должен ссылаться!

   существуют, конечно, всякие «загрузочные менеджеры» (типа упомянутого в комментариях [*easybcd*](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/)), а вот реализован ли хоть в каком-либо из них автоматический учёт обновления в *stage2*-файле того же *grub-а*, я не знаю. но подозреваю, что вряд ли (учитывая, во-первых, что разедов с *grub-ами* может быть значительно больше одного, а во-вторых, что «инициатива обновления» приходит со стороны *grub-а*, который, вполне естественно, вряд ли подозревает о существовании каких-либо «менеджеров загрузки»).
2. в случае загрузчика *grub* подход диаметрально противоположен: всё (что возможно) сделано для упрощения настройки процесса загрузки других операционных систем. в «обычных условиях» всё вообще происходит «автомагически»: в процессе установки программы *grub* (и при обновлении файлов, содержащих *stage2*) вызывается программа *update-grub* (входит в состав пакета *grub*), которая (как правило, вполне удачно) «находит» на блочных устройствах и их разделах другие загрузчики, и добавляет пункты с ними в загрузочное меню.

какой путь вам больше подходит — выбирайте сами.

---

p.s. пожалуй, стоит отметить, что код «загрузчика второй стадии» программы *grub* давно разросся до такой степени, что разработчикам пришлось создать (правда, не только по этой причине) промежуточный загрузчик (который назвали *stage 1.5*). сути это не меняет, но про стадии 1, 1.5 и 2 написано даже [в википедии](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB), и упоминание будет уместным.

---

**дополнение**

по поводу того, куда ставить 512 байт *stage1*, чтобы не затереть *mbr*: ставьте не в *mbr* диска, а в [*vbr* раздела](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_boot_record). там есть достаточно места. установщики загрузчиков об этом знают, и умеют с ним обращаться.

Comment: Цель сохранения виндового загрузчика первичным - получение возможности [однократной перезагрузки в выбранную систему](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/492090/178988). EasyBCD умеет выполнять поиск загрузчиков. Он точно находил grub legacy, который нормально работал из виндового - надеюсь, что он разберётся и со свежим.

Comment: *получение возможности однократной перезагрузки в выбранную систему* — нда, что только программисты не придумают, лишь бы один байтик в текстовом файле не перезаписывать. это я про вынесение каталога `/boot` в отдельный раздел с фс *fat*. (можно даже и не весь каталог `/boot`, а конкретно `/boot/grub/`).

Answer (score 0):

Всё очень просто - ntldr, используемый по сей день, не умеет читать ext4 и прочие ФС, которые обычно используются для grub. Нужно грузить grub через ntldr - пожалуйста, выводите grub на раздел с fat32 или ntfs. А установить grub без перезаписи бут-сектора реально, но сложно, если используется debian/ubuntu, т. к. в их пакетах прописана перезапись бут-сектора при установке grub'a.

Comment: Я несколько намудрил... Но в целом у меня получилось. Только я не уверен, на каком разделе сейчас grub. Вероятно мне вообще следовало не задавать этот вопрос, а посмотреть значения дропдауна с типом загрузчика в EasyBCD... Потом проверю отдельно.